# Viewing blockchain blocks using Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

How can I fetch and view the blocks added to the blockchain when using Hyperledger Composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using [composer-client](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/allData#client-api). Although there are no convenience methods available for this purpose, it is possible to call down to the underlying Hyperledger Fabric SDK API.

Here's some example code for fetching a block by number and pretty-printing it to the console:

```
const { inspect } = require('util');
const { BusinessNetworkConnection } = require('composer-client');

async function run() {
  const connection = new BusinessNetworkConnection();

  // Connect to the blockchain using admin credentials.
  // These credentials should be available in your local keystore.
  await connection.connect('admin@network');

  // Native API provided through the Fabric SDK, allows much more low-level operations than Composer.
  const nativeApi = connection.getNativeAPI();

  // Connect to the channel where the transactions are happening, the default is "composerchannel".
  const channel = nativeApi.getChannel('composerchannel');

  // Grab a block by it's number
  const block = await channel.queryBlock(4);

  // Enter the matrix
  console.log(inspect(block, { depth: null, colors: true, compact: false }));

  await connection.disconnect();
}

run();
```

More information about what functionality is exposed through this API can be found in the [fabric-sdk-node documentation](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/index.html).

Comment: have you seen the Hyperledger Explorer? https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I did consider using Hyperledger Explorer, but it seemed a bit overkill to have to install Postgresql and other dependencies just for this simple use case.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Explorer does this, but it's not a part of Hyperledger Composer. It's a native Fabric tool.